# Setting the path for the ie driver in Thucydides does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, thucydides

In my thucydides.properties file I have the Following:

```
webdriver.ie.driver = C:\\Users\\Scott-H\\IEDriverServer.exe
webdriver.chrome.driver = C:\\Users\\Scott-H\\chromedriver.exe
```

chrome works fine internet explorer does not. To get ie to run I have to manualy set the system properties as so in my tests.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Scott-H\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

> FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE

does anyone have any ideas why one would work but not the other?

```
@Story(Application.Search.SearchByKeyword.class)
@RunWith(ThucydidesRunner.class)
public class CreateContactTest {
@Managed
public WebDriver driver;
```

Where the driver is being created

Comment: What error are you getting??

Comment: FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE. sorry forgot that bit.

Comment: Where are you creating your driver? can you post that code?

Comment: its being created in the test.

Comment: After setting property for IE..Have uo initialized global driver by creating new instance?

Comment: As said by Saritha Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

To make chromedriver or iedriver work, their location must be in system PATH, or set by System.setProperty. If one work and another doesn't, it probably means they are not in PATH, and one of them is set elsewhere, while the other is not. I think your framework configuration sets chromedriver path somewhere, but doesn't do the same for IEDriver.